# Authorization code Spotify web API Java michaelthelin

Tags: java, spotify

I am using the michaelthelin wrapper for the Spotify API in Java and I seem to understand everything but the authorization code as I need it in order to proceed but I have no idea where to actually et it. This is a part of my code where the authorization code is required.

```
static AuthorizationCodeRequest authorizationCodeRequest = spotifyApi.authorizationCode(code).build();

public static void authorizationCode_Sync() {
    try {
        AuthorizationCodeCredentials authorizationCodeCredentials = authorizationCodeRequest.execute();
        System.out.println(code);

        // Set access and refresh token for further "spotifyApi" object usage
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getAccessToken());
        spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getRefreshToken());

        System.out.println("Expires in: " + authorizationCodeCredentials.getExpiresIn());
    } catch (IOException | SpotifyWebApiException | ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The program doesn't run obviousy without the code so does anyone know how to get it?

I've looked at a bunch of things to fix it but I couldn't find anything helpful.